# Change ServletRequest server name programmatically

Tags: java, spring, grails

I need to change the serverName of the `ServletRequest` object in my Grails controller. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this since the serverName is a read-only property.

Comment: I mean the `serverName` of the `HttpRequest`. I've tried creating my own `HttpRequest` but I don't think that's advisable since I'm not an expert and I might do more harm than good.

Comment: Uhh. Maybe I should say the `ServletRequest` interface's getServerName? I need to get that server name because my app is a multitenant app and I need to change the server name programatically so I can switch the tenant programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most correct thing to do is probably to set up a clever filter or redirect which "fixes" your request URL before your servlet even gets involved.  I know nothing about how to do that; you should ask on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) if you want to do that.

In java, you can fake it by creating your own subclass of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which provides `setServerName()` and overrides `getServerName()` while delegating all other methods to the superclass.  You can then provide a filter which creates an instance of your request and sends that one down the chain.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
             FilterChain chain) 
             throws IOException, ServletException {
  YourHttpServletRequest yourRequest =
              new YourHttpServletRequest(request, newServerName);
  chain.doFilter(yourRequest, response);
}
```

Comment: If anyone knows how to do the fix-the-incoming-URL solution, feel free to update the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and accept this if it works. Will also ask on serverfault.

Comment: Do you know how to add a filter to web.xml?  I can update the answer if you like.

Comment: Yup. I've thought about adding a filter but I didn't know how I was supposed to change the serverName anyway. Thanks for the help, man.

Comment: Sadly. I can't use this since I can't change the `request` object in grails. Thanks for the help anyway, man.

Comment: Can you not write the filter in Java?  One little jar in your WEB-INF/lib directory would work..

Comment: Ok. I retried doing this. And I found out that the reason it wasn't working was because the `url-pattern` I gave doesn't work. I tried setting it to `/*` and it works. Thanks! I just need to fix the `url-pattern`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, CORS filter might help
I've used http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html in my previous project.

But you can also lookup on github for example https://github.com/eBay/cors-filter

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me either. I can already send requests to the other server. I just need to either access the SecurityContextHolder of that server or change the server name before sending my request. I still can't figure out how to do either using the CORS filter.